Cancel button missing on Account adding page
We have a page created for our partners to add new account. The users are redirected to the account adding page using a custom button. The button redirects the user to the Standard Salesforce page "/s/createrecord/NewAccount".
One thing that is missing on that page is the "Cancel" or "Back" button on that page. How to enable those on standard salesforce page?
